# AES encryption between Python server and React Native client

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, react-native, encryption, aes

I'm trying to transmit encrypted data from a React Native client to a Python server. I'm using the [`react-native-aes-crypto`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-aes-crypto) module for the same. I tried to follow [this article](https://itnext.io/sharing-aes-256-encrypted-data-between-node-js-and-python-3-d0c87eae212b) first but got stuck when `tweetnacl-util` refused to go well with React Native. I tried to use `browserify` to use the native `crypto` module with JavaScript but that didn't decrypt correctly with Python.

I generated the key using `os.urandom(16)` in Python and used that in both sides.

Now, this key also throws an error

```
Error: exception decoding Hex string: invalid characters encountered in Hex string
promiseMethodWrapper@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2244:45
```

Client side:

```
const key = 'a random key'
const encryptData = (text, key) => {
    return Aes.randomKey(16).then(iv => {
        return Aes.encrypt(text, key, iv).then(cipher => ({
            cipher,
            iv,
        }))
    })
}

socket.onopen = () => {
    encryptData('Some random text', key).then(({cipher, iv})=>{
        socket.send(JSON.stringify({'cipher': cipher, 'iv': iv}))
    })
 }
```

Back end:

```
# this code was taken straight from the article. I don't know what to do with it
async def recieve_messages(websocket, path):
    secret_key = b'a random key'
    encrypted = await websocket.recv()
    encrypted = json.loads(encrypted)
    encrypted = encrypted["cipher"]
    print(encrypted)
    encrypted = encrypted.split(':')
    # We decode the two bits independently
    nonce = b64decode(encrypted[0])
    encrypted = b64decode(encrypted[1])
    # We create a SecretBox, making sure that out secret_key is in bytes
    box = SecretBox(bytes(secret_key, encoding='utf8'))
    decrypted = box.decrypt(encrypted, nonce).decode('utf-8')
    print(decrypted)
    await websocket.close(1000)

start_server = websockets.serve(recieve_messages, "localhost", 5000)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)

try:
    print("Server is running")
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Server is stopping")
```

I'm new to AES as a whole and I'm stuck here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which line of code produces - Error: exception decoding Hex string: invalid characters encountered in Hex string ??

Comment: The `Aes.encrypt()` produces that. When I use the `Aes.pbkdf2()` as mentioned in the docs, this works but I can't generate a key every time for this project. I can't transport the key during websocket communication.